# Extracting info from data from api in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

I am currently stuck at a React Native video tutorial in YouTube. [image: My Current Situation]

I received the data but cannot extract the info out of it. I ran Thunder Client and my data is as follows:

> {
> "businesses": [
> {
> "id": "qVQCTqt74Lgq235sfUvtzw",
> "alias": "fatboys-the-burger-bar-singapore-7",
> "name": "Fatboy's The Burger Bar",
> "image_url": "https://s3-media2.fl.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/hwUj8zzKoA3s_nN6WLdwRQ/o.jpg",
> "is_closed": false,
> "url": "https://www.yelp.com/biz/fatboys-the-burger-bar-singapore-7?adjust_creative=9vPgH7ZRB8WcPG-_Pr01YQ&utm_campaign=yelp_api_v3&utm_medium=api_v3_business_search&utm_source=9vPgH7ZRB8WcPG-_Pr01YQ",
> "review_count": 19,
> "categories": [
> ... }

Comment: Please make it a little easier for others to help you - first add your code as text, not as an image, and then specify what you're trying to do with the data. As of now this doesn't really contain a question and may be closed.